# How to tell which Sharepoint version I have

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to figure out if I have the enterprise version of the trial installed, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint have three versions:

- First is called WSS (Windows SharePoint Services) and is the free one.
- Second is the standard and is called MOSS (Microsoft Office SharePoint Server) Standard. This one don't have the Infopath Services enabled, so you can't show it in "Central Administration".
- Third is the enterprise and is called MOSS Enterprise. This one have all features.

So, which one did you install?

Comment: you are saying the only way to tell if i have Enterprise is if Infopath is enabled, isn't there a way to tell from the version number or some working/description somewhere. the problem is I downloaded the trial, and I do not know which version i downloaded.

Comment: This is the quick way to know it, but you can go to Central Admin -> Operations -> Upgrade and Migration -> Enable Enterprise Features and here you can know it. Please, look the same answer in this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349383/how-to-check-if-moss-standard-or-moss-enterprise-is-installed]